# GridView Events in Nested UserControl

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using Nested User Controls....

Like: I have a 'A' User control that contains the grid view then a 'B' User Control that contains 'A' and one more user control then a 'C' user Control that Contains 'B' and 2 more user controls...

I want row command in the 'C' user control

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is two ways that you can achieve this.

Expose the grid view with a public property in your A control. In your B control expose the A control as a public property. So in your C control you can write something like

```
bControl.aControl.GridProperty.OnRowCommand += youreventhandler;
```

Or you can define an event on A control such as OnInnerGridRowCommand and raise this event to B control when RowCommand happens. Define another event in B control and raise this new event with appropriate parameters when OnInnerGridRowCommand of A happens. So you can handle this new event in control C.

---

This is C user control exposing inner grid

```
public GridView GridView_In_C
{
    get { return innerGrid; }
}
```

This is B user control exposing C

```
public CWebUserControl C_In_B
{
    get
    {
        return CWebUserControl_In_B;
    }
}
```

This is A user control exposing B

```
public BWebUserControl B_In_A
{
    get
    {
        return BWebUserControl_In_A;
    }
}
```

And this is a page, hosting A user control and attaching to RowCommand,

```
public partial class HostPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AWebUserControlInHostPage.B_In_A.C_In_B.GridView_In_C.RowCommand += new GridViewCommandEventHandler(InnerGridView_RowCommand);
    }

    void InnerGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks .....but i am not able to understand in =>bControl.aControl.GridProperty.OnRowCommand += youreventhandler;
What is bControl and aControl....are they the public Properties...or..??????